# Wrapping text in spinner android

Tags: android, spinner

I have long text that I want to put in a few, but not all, items in a spinner.  Tried using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107500/how-to-wrap-lengthy-text-in-a-spinner) but was not able to get it to work.  I created and saved multiline_spinner_dropdown_item.xml in res/layout directory but still get an error "multiline_spinner_dropdown_item cannot be resolved" in Eclipse.

Comment: can you show the erroneous code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1" 
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

Use this textview in your spinner adapter in place of the android default textview you are using in .setAdapter method of the Spinner. see below R.layout.spinner_textview textview is this textview i have posted above.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), 
                                                                         R.array.Array, 
                                                                        R.layout.spinner_textview);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Works fine, seems that the main sticking point with the original post was the use of "this" instead of "getApplicationContext()"  I also had to change android:singleLine="true" to android:singleLine="false" Next issue is getting the drop down dialog to show two lines of text.  I also noticed that this cannot be applied to more than one spinner contained in that activity

Comment: oh sry tht i forgot to change single line false. you can apply this text view to multiple spinners in same activity you have to make different adapter.