# Android: Wrapping long text in Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

In my string array i have a long text that I want to display in my Spinner(this Spinner is in a dialog)..i tried the below code

```
 spinner1 = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.quesspinner);
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.fbquestion);
            arrayAdapter .setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview);
            spinner1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

and my text view as below

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

this is working for most people, but not for me not sure where I am going wrong;
did according to this SO questions [How to wrap lengthy text in a spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107500/how-to-wrap-lengthy-text-in-a-spinner)

[Wrapping text in spinner android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384639/wrapping-text-in-spinner-android)

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want your text on several line or to ellipsize ?

Comment: it should fit the mobile screen..mutilines is ok too...i tried using short text still not comming ..maybe problem with my adapter?

Comment: Your current code is implementing the second link solution right ? What is the result on your screen ?

Comment: @Plumillon I can see three lines..but more than three line its not visible

Comment: the old answers do not work for Android 4.0+