# How can I have multiple lines in a Spinner option

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-spinner

I need to put different lines in a Spinner I tried to put in the xml file `android:singleLine="false"` and writing `\n` as you can see in the example but nothing work. What I need exactly isn't just to adjust the text for see it correctly. I need to specify when I want to jump line.

Here is the format of each option in the Spinner I want:

---

```
TITLE: XXXXX "\n"
property1: xxxx property2: xxxx
```

---

Here is a resume of my code:

```
s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(Activity_introducir.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,nomactivitats(s.getSelectedItem().toString()));
s2.setAdapter(adapter2);


private ArrayList nomactivitats(String nomproj) {
...
array_activitats.add(cc.getString(3) + " \n  Example Text in next line");
...
return array_activitats;
}
```

Comment: see where it says `android.R.layout.simple_spinner`? 

What you need to do is make your own spinner layout that accepts it.

Comment: Just look around for tutorials on how to make your own spinner in Android. You can create the whole format of a row in your Spinner. [Here's](http://stephenpengilley.blogspot.in/2013/01/android-custom-spinner-tutorial.html) one.

Comment: This question has already been [answered][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107500/how-to-wrap-lengthy-text-in-a-spinner