# Customizing AutoCompleteTextView Google Place Search to show longer text

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, google-places-api, autocompletetextview

I am trying to customize the AutoCompleteTextView with Google place search but facing following issues with the UI. Refer the sample screenshots below:
[image]

1. The drop down list overlaps with some part of the text view. I want it to start at bottom edge of the text view. Here is the layout I'm using for the AutoCompleteTextView:

   ```
           <AutoCompleteTextView
               android:id="@+id/searchPlace"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:imeOptions="actionNext"
               android:gravity="start"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:singleLine="true"
               android:maxLines="1"
               android:textColor="@color/black"
               android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
               android:background="@android:color/white" />
   ```
2. When the result text is longer than the width of the AutoCompleteTextView, I want to make the result list item multi-line so that entire text can be visible. I tried with custom layout for the text view but its not working. Here is the layout of the list item:

   ```
       <TextView
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:id="@+id/autoCompleteItem"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
               android:textSize="@dimen/font_18"
               android:singleLine="false"
               android:padding="5dp"
               android:background="@color/white"
               android:textColor="@color/black"
           />
   ```
3. Once I select the text from the suggestions and the text is longer than AutoCompleteTextView width, the text is justified at the end of the text. I would like it to be at the start of the view. i.e. It should display the starting text and ellipsize the ending text. (Layout as in question#1 above).
   [image]

This is the adapter I'm using if that matters:

```
PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter mAdapter = new PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter(mContext, R.layout.custom_item, mGoogleApiClient, placeSearchBounds, null);
```

Comment: this question is already well explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107500/how-to-wrap-lengthy-text-in-a-spinner)

Comment: They are not same. This is about AutoCompleteTextView not EditText or TextView in general.